# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ItemsModule') using Angular + NGXS

Tags: angular, ngxs

I'm using Angular with [NGXS](https://www.ngxs.io/) store, usually everything works fine, but i've quite strange problem with the pretty-much basic case.

State:

```
@State({
   name: 'items',
   defaults
})
class ItemsState {
   constructor(private itemsService: ItemsService) {}

   ...
}
```

Module:

```
@NgModule([
   imports: [
      NgxsModule.forFeature([ ItemsState ])
   ]
])
ItemsModule {}
```

Service:

```
@Service({ providedIn: 'root' })
ItemsService { ... }
```

Error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ItemsModule')`

Angular version: 15.2.9
NGXS version: 3.8.1

It took some time to localize the problem, but i found that everything works fine if I'm removing the `NxsModule.forFeature(...)` import, or using a different state class.
In case if i'm trying to import the same feature module with `ItemsState` into the different module - everything works fine, I'm also able to use different state in `ItemsModule`, but this particular combination gives an error.

What could be the problem?

Comment: I had similar error when I had some circular references. Check imports in ItemsState, and make sure it doesnt import (directly on indirectly) anything that's dependent on it

Comment: @MG seems like you're right, there was a quite deep and non-obvious circular dependency. Thanks for a tip!